# Quantity Update when changing Usr Field on Adjusments Screen

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've Added 2 USR Fields to change the Qty of the Transactions grid on the Adjustment Screen the Usr Fields Usage is the following...

The 1st one (Qty On Hand) contains the Qty On hand they have of this item in the selected location and LotSerialNbr.

The 2nd one (Physical Qty) it's to set the remaining qty they want to have on the (Location - LotSerialNbr).

When the user open the Adjustments Screen it shows both fields with the same Quantities, for example, Qty On Hand = 100 and Physical Qty = 100 so the Qty of the transactions screen must be Zero (meaning they don't want to adjust anything) if the user changes the physical quantity the system needs to calculate what is the Qty to Adjust, for example, Qty on Hand = 100 and Physical Qty = 50 means the Qty must have -50 so Acumatica Adjust the Qty to 50.

I've tried to do this by changing the Qty on the FieldUpdated event of the Physical Qty USR field but the LotSerialNbr fades away sometimes and in the RowUpdated Event of INTran the Total Qty of the Adjustment doesn't change its value

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<INTranTGExt.usrQtyPhysical> e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;

        INTran iNTranRow = (INTran)e.Row;

        INTranTGExt iNTranTGExtRow = PXCache<INTran>.GetExtension<INTranTGExt>(iNTranRow);

        Base.transactions.Cache.SetValueExt<INTran.qty>(iNTranRow, (iNTranTGExtRow.UsrQtyOnHand - (iNTranTGExtRow.UsrQtyPhysical)) * (-1));
    }

    protected virtual void _(Events.RowUpdated<INTran> e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;

        INTran iNTranRow = (INTran)e.Row;

        INTranTGExt iNTranTGExtRow = PXCache<INTran>.GetExtension<INTranTGExt>(iNTranRow);

        Base.transactions.Cache.SetValueExt<INTran.qty>(iNTranRow, (iNTranTGExtRow.UsrQtyOnHand - (iNTranTGExtRow.UsrQtyPhysical)) * (-1));
    }
```

Comment: You speak about FieldSelected, but in your code sample you show FieldUpdated and RowUpdated. What is the reason behind this discrepancy?

Comment: @YuriyZaletskyy You're totally right about that, I've edited the question. I'm trying to be able to do the adjustment indicating the Physical Qty is going to be remaining after the release. I don't know why the FieldUpdated makes the LotSerialNbr fade away and the RowUpdated doesn't seem to be raising some native Acumatica event definition.